# remove space after comma(,) in item name using sql

Tags: sql

my table contains item_name like

```
FIZZY  , Each

KENT  , Each
```

i want remove the space before comma, like

```
FIZZY, Each
```

i found these items by using : `select * from item where item_name like '% ,%'`
help me to remove the space.

Comment: Which _version_ of SQL are you using?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: Why are you storing multiple values in a delimited string?  That would appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE item
SET item_name = REPLACE(item_name, ' ,', ',')
WHERE item_name LIKE '% ,%';
```

Depending on your actual SQL database, we might be able to use a more focused regex replacement.

Comment: is this for updating all the itemname or particular itemname only /

Comment: The `WHERE` clause I used would target only those records having a space before a comma, but you don't really need it, because the replacement would have no effect on non matching records anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this does what you really want:

```
select replace(replace(item_name, ' ', ''), ',', ', ')
```

This removes all spaces and then adds one back in after commas.

Comment: Good catch +1.  I missed the multiple spaces.  But, this assumes that spaces would not appear in the data itself.  If so, then your first replacement would remove actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. This will keep your other spaces as it is.

```
UPDATE item
SET item_name = REPLACE(item_name,'  ,',',')
```